# Increase layout height only from one end of the layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I'm trying to create some nice animations where I will have my layout's height expand from the bottom end of it (which is aprox in the middle of the screen) - towards the bottom of the screen.

I've tried playing around with LayoutParams and animating it but couldn't succeed.

**I guess this splits into two questions:**

1) How do I animate a layout's height change?

2) How do I make the layout animation, change only the bottom part of the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could animate the view's Height attribute using a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) or [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html), from its current value to the screen height.

Your view would have a height that isn't constrained by anything (such as being above anything in the case of a relative layout, or part of a linear layout, etc) and is set to a specific value, which could be done at run time (set height to 1/2 screen height on view created).  The top of the view would be anchored at the top some how (such as align parent top = true).

Comment: I have managed to animate the value, thank you for that. The layout it expanded in both ways - extending the top and the bottom. Anchoring the layout to be         android:layout_centerInParent="true" did not help. How can I set it to expand only in one direction?

Comment: Again this is where you need to make sure it's anchored at the top.  Try setting alignParentTop to true.  If you centre the view in its parent, then as it expands it will re-centre and appear to grow from both ends.